# How to make SOLR 8.11.1 Ping api call return xml instead of json

Tags: solr

I have an app that accesses cores on a SOLR 4.10.2 instance. I am updating to SOLR 8.11.1.

My app calls the ping api in 4.10.2: the results are returned in xml format. When I make the same call in SOLR 8.11.1, the results are returned in json format.

Is there a setting (in solrconfig.xml? or at a SOLR core ...) that will set the default result type to xml in 8.11.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default queryResponseWriter can be configured in the solrconfig.xml for the core.

I was looking at the solrconfig.xml for the core, and there is a commented section that shows how to set the default as xml:

```
 <queryResponseWriter name="xml"
                      default="true"
                      class="solr.XMLResponseWriter" />
```

I moved it out of the comment, reloaded the core, and ping now returns xml.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the response is managed by the `wt` parameter in the request. In your case you can simply call

```
http://mysolrserver/solr/mycore/admin/ping?wt=xml
```

and you'll get an XML response also from SOLR 8.11.1

Ref: [solr documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/response-writers.html)